# MySQL SELECT NOW() and PHP date('Y-m-d H:i:s') are different

Tags: php, mysql, linux, centos

I am on VPS Clound hosting and the difference between MySQL SELECT NOW() and PHP date('Y-m-d H:i:s') is 4 hours. What is the problem?

Comment: Nothing is the problem both are separate things and have separate time you have to adjust one of the server time to correct point

Comment: May be useful: [Temporarily change PHP's timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP and MySQL are set to two different time zones. Both are configurable at the server- and individual execution/connection levels.

Comment: How can I fix it? I have kloxo.

Comment: Read the manuals (not kidding, PHP and MySQL have extremely newbie-friendly documentation). PHP is configured by editing `php.ini` (usually at `/etc/php.ini`) and MySQL is configured by editing `my.cnf` (usually at `/etc/my.cnf`). Set them both to the same time zone, restart your web server, restart MySQL, and you'll get the same time from both.

Comment: Although, if he is on a shared host he probably cannot change those settings.  In that case, off to customer support with ye!  Best of luck.

Comment: thank you very much, I will be trying it now. And, Chris, I have my own hosting, not shared. And I am really newbie to these things.

Comment: @Chris mysql and php both support setting the timezone for the current session without having to change the server setting. So even on shared hosts, you can get around the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Time zones. One of the big three suspects (MySQL, Webserver, System) has a different TZ configuration than the others. One's probably defaulting to GMT/UTC, and the other's set to the server's local timezone.